# LINQ: Convert Dictionary<int, List<MyObject>> to List<List<string>>

Tags: c#, linq

My `Dictionary<int, List<MyObject>> result` has..

```
Key               Value
1                 {"Chicago", 100}
1                 {"Newyork", 200}
2                 {"Minneapolis", 300}
```

want to convert it to `List<List<string>>` in below format.

```
{"Index", "City","Value"},
{1, "Chicago", 100},
{1, "Newyork", 200}
{2, "Minneapolis", 300}
```

This is what I have achieved so far

```
 var list = result.Select(rec => new                 
    {
        Index = rec.Key,
        City = rec.Value.Select(rec1 => rec1.City),
        Value = rec.Value.Select(rec1 => rec1.Value)
    }).ToList();
```

What I am getting is this..

```
{"Index", "City", "Value"},
{1, System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator<MyObject, string>, System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator<MyObject, int>},
{1, System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator<MyObject, string>, System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator<MyObject, int>},
{2, System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator<MyObject, string>, System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator<MyObject, int>}
```

May be I am missing Where condition. Please suggest.

```
public class MyObject
{
        public MyObject(){}
        public string City{get;set;}
        public int Value{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: why a List<List<string>>? A multi dimensional array would be fine for this? Or you could just add the index as a property to the object

Comment: In the first section: Why your dictionary is able to contain multiple Keys of 1? This isn't possible as far as I know.

Comment: what about `result.ToList()` before `Select`?

Comment: `Select` just returns an iterator instead of the actual collection. You´d have to call `ToList` to print the elements. However you should also write some logic that loops the elements in each of those collections, because otherwise you´d get sometjing like `System.Collections.Generic.List<MyObject, string>`.

Comment: @sebi, my dictionary contains two keys. 1 & 2. 1 has two records. What I have written here is just presentation how it looks.

Comment: @user1 Ok makes sense :)

Comment: You haven't shown your `MyObject`.

Comment: @user1, check my solution below. I think it's suitable for your requirment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the output like this?

[image: Do you need the output like this?]

I have a solution for you. Try it.

```
Dictionary<int, List<MyObject>> result = new Dictionary<int, List<MyObject>>();

result.Add(1, new List<MyObject>() { new MyObject() { City = "Chicago", Value = 100 }, new MyObject() { City = "Newyork", Value = 200 } });
result.Add(2, new List<MyObject>() { new MyObject() { City = "Minneapolis", Value = 300 } });

var resultYouWant = result.SelectMany(p => p.Value.Select(a => new { Index = p.Key, a.City, a.Value })).ToList();
```

Comment: You're not creating a `List<List<string>>` as required by the OP. Are you?

Comment: {"Index", "City","Value"},
{1, "Chicago", 100},
{1, "Newyork", 200}
{2, "Minneapolis", 300}
=> I thought it is not List<List<string>> structure. Is it right?

Comment: This is what the OP has done already and this is not what he needs. He wants all elements of the internal `List` to be of string type.

Comment: Please help me give an example about expected output that the OP wants. I added a picture of the output

Comment: I did small change. var resultYouWant = result.SelectMany(p => p.Value.Select(a => new { Index = p.Key, City = a.City, Value = a.Value })).ToList();

Comment: @user1: You explicitly asked for `List<List<string>>`, which is not what this answer produces.

Answer (score 4):

This is what you need:

```
var Result =  result.SelectMany(r => r.Value.Select(x => new[] { r.Key.ToString(), x.City, x.Value.ToString() }.ToList()));
```

To prepend column names as the first element of the outer list:

```
Result.Insert(0, {"Index", "City","Value"}.ToList());
```

Comment: I want column names as well. {"Index", "City","Value"},

Comment: @user1: As the first element of the bigger list?

Comment: I applied your suggested code changes. Compiler complains that No best type found for implicitly-typed array.

Comment: Compiler is unable to recognize what that "new[]" is for

Comment: MyObject doesn't have Index property but output result does have it.

Comment: @See my edit. Your Index element is generated by the `Key` of your Dictionary. It compiles fine for me. See if u missed something.

Answer (score 0):

below code is work for you but not getting what is your usecase.

```
var list = result.Select(rec => new
               {
                  Index = rec.Key,
                  City = rec.Value.City),
                  Value = rec.Value.Value)
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: This shouldn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
City = rec.Value.Select(rec1 => rec1.City),
```

That is creating an IEnumerable, not a string. Which is why you get System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator out of it.

You may be better off using for loops here.

```
foreach(var kvp in result)
    foreach(var value in kvp)
        //Create string here and add it to your list.
```

Comment: Sorry, LINQ only!

Comment: grrrrrrrrrrrrr.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Although, I think there is some merit to the old foreach sometimes.

Comment: @user1 Why Linq only? You did not mention this at all, furthermore when you have the loops you probably also can easily write the Linq-statements for it. Quite often Linq makes it more complicated and is harder to read, so I condier this an easy and good answer.